# .htaccess redirect when arguments are included ("index.php?value=2")

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Would anyone have suggestions on how to redirect a URL that has variables in it?

It looks like "www.homepage.com/index.php?value=home/index" would like it to simply redirect to "www.homepage.com"

I've tried:

```
Redirect /index.php?value=home/index /index
```

But it seems like "Redirect" ignores everything passed the question mark character. Is that so? Any way around it?

I am not familiar with regex, so I was hoping a simple solution is available without using that.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture `Query String` like `value=home/index`use `mod_rewrite`

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)=(.+)/(.+)$
RewriteRule ^     /?       [L,R]
```

`Redirect` is `mod_alias` and that is designed to handle simple URL manipulation tasks. For more complicated tasks such as manipulating the `query string`, use the tools provided by mod_rewrite.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: @willer2k glad to help , Thanks